# laravel 4 Route::controller() method returns NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, controller, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to route to a RESTful controller using the following in app/routes.php:

```
Route::controller('register', 'RegisterController');

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

In my app/controllers/RegisterController.php file I have added the following:

```
<?php

class RegisterController extends BaseController 
{
    public function getRegister()
    {
        return View::make('registration');
    }

    public function postRegister()
    {
    $data = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'first_name' => array('alpha', 'min:3'),
        'last_name' => array('alpha', 'min:3'),
        'company_name' => array('alpha_num'),
        'phone_number' => 'regex:[0-9()\-]'
    );  
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        return 'Data was saved.';
    }
    return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

When I run php artisan routes in terminal I get:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                              | Name | Action                     | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET /register/register/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}  |      | Register@getRegister       |                |               |
|        | POST /register/register/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5} |      | Register@postRegister      |                |               |
|        | GET /register/{_missing}                         |      | Register@missingMethod     |                |               |
|        | GET /                                            |      | HomeController@showWelcome |                |               |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

I don't understand why register is showing twice in the URI and the second GET action is missing and why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using RESTful API, the best way is in your route,

```
Route::resource('register', 'RegisterController');
```

And change your `public function getRegister()` to `public function index()` and `public function postRegister()` to `public function store()`

Then the `index()` can be access using `GET http://localhost/laravel/register` and the `store()` using `POST http://localhost/laravel/register`

Chaneg the `http://localhost/laravel/` with yours.

And the same way the `update($id)` is used for update and `destroy($id)` is used for delete

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thanks for the fast and insightful response. I guess I need to research the difference of using Route::resource() vs Route::controller(). Cheers!

Comment: @GeekyGoon if you like, check some of my similar answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196636/laravel-restful-controller-parameters/19196884#19196884 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190389/laravel-4-remove-index-on-default-getindex-controller-function/19193669#19193669 then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124018/laravel-retrieving-data-from-rest-api/19132837#19132837

Comment: If you want to go `Route::controller('register', 'RegisterController')` way, you can use the function names `getIndex` and `postIndex` to achieve the same results.

see: [Restful-controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

Comment: Thanks, after both of your responses I realize it makes more sense to allow the UsersController to handle the creation of the new user. I'm getting it all together...

Answer (score 1):

Route::controller('register', 'RegisterController');

This will also work if you change it

Route::controller('/', 'RegisterController');